# Automate tasks on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, automation, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the best way to automate tasks such as "Exit and Childlock" on chrome browser in one-click (the ideal will be with a keyboard shortcut for it also..)?

Answer (score 1):

I've also been looking for a keyboard shortcut but have not found one. 
Currently I'm using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) with the following script to create a one-key solution:

```
#z::
  WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
  IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
  {
    SetTitleMatchMode 1
    WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    MouseClick ,left, Width - 142, 7
    ;sleep, 50
    MouseClick ,left, 131, 284
    ;sleep, 50
    WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Send !{F4}
  }
```

Still a working progress. Please share improvements.